# Images are not shown

Tags: images

I can see my images in media/libary but not in posts.

The issue seems to be that the REAL url to the image ends with image.jpg (if I go to this url I can see the image). But in the post I get the "broken image link"-icon. And when I check the image url it ends with image-sizeXsize.jpg, so Wordpress for some reason adds sizeXsize (example 1000x1000). How do I solve this?

Edit1: I have just installed WP. Have tried the theams twenty eleven and twenty fifteen, same problem. I have installed alot of plugins, will take a look at those.

Edit2: I have deactivaded all plugins, still same problem. Latest WP version.

Comment: Embedding/Image-resizing's not the issue, issue is somewhere else. Deactivate all your plugins, turn WP_DEBUG on and switch to default theme one by one to find out where actually the problem is.

Comment: Do you getting image load proper in default theme? If yes then my be your theme issue.

Comment: Edit1: I have just installed WP. Have tried the theams twenty eleven and twenty fifteen, same problem. I have installed alot of plugins, will take a look at those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is problem with your image thumbnail. May be it doesn't exists.

You can fix this by instaling [Regenerate thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin.
Then generate thumbnails for all media files.

Another way is to include image in post or page with full url. You can do this by selecting image size to "Full Size" in `Attachment Display Settings` in media uploader popup box.
[image]